# Update View In Angular ON Button Click

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-material

I have a list of items on the screen with a button next to them. When I click the button it sends an API request to change a particular value in the backend. So next time we refresh the page, the item doesn't show up in the list.

Instead of manually refreshing the page, I want the component to update it's view automatically.
How can I achieve this?

component.ts

```
  constructor(private DetailApi: DetailserviceService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { 
    this.status_type = "published";
    this.getLeads();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getLeads = () => {
    console.log(this.status_type);
    this.DetailApi.getAllDetails(this.status_type).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.lead_list = data;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }

  togglePublishValue = (id) => {
    this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/toggle/" + id + "/",{
      headers: this.httpHeaders
    }).subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
    )
    this.getLeads();

  }

  showPublished(){
    return this.status_type === "published";
  }

  showUnpublished(){
    return this.status_type === "unpublished";
  }

  showUnverified(){
    return this.status_type === "unverified";
  }

  ToggleValue(){
    if(this.status_type === "published"){
      return "Published";
    }
    else if(this.status_type === "unpublished"){
      return "Unpublished";
    }
    else{
      return "Pending";
    }
  }

  onToggleBtn(){
    this.getLeads();
    console.log(this.status_type);
  }
```

HTML

```
    <mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" style="width:100%" (click)="onToggleBtn()" [(ngModel)]="status_type" aria-label="Font Style">
        <mat-button-toggle style="width:100%" value="published">Published</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle style="width:100%" value="unpublished">Unpublished</mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle style="width:100%" value="unverified">Verification Pending</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
    <div class="tabular">
      <h2> {{ToggleValue()}}</h2>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          function displayResult()
          {
              var index = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
              var new_row = '<td>'+index+'</td><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td>';
              document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = new_row;
          }
        </script>    
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Event Title</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <div *ngIf="showUnpublished()">
                <tr *ngFor="let obj of lead_list">
                    <td (click)="onClick(obj.id)">{{obj.event_title}}</td>
                    <td><button (click)="togglePublishValue(obj.id)" mat-raised-button>Publish</button></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="showPublished()">
                <tr *ngFor="let obj of lead_list">
                    <td (click)="onClick(obj.id)" >{{obj.event_title}}</td>
                    <td><button (click)="togglePublishValue(obj.id)" mat-raised-button>Unpublish</button></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="showUnverified()">
                <tr *ngFor="let obj of lead_list">
                    <td (click)="onClick(obj.id)" >{{obj.event_title}}</td>
                    <td><button mat-raised-button disabled>Publish</button></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) to update your UI with data of e.g. services which are not in zone. `this.ngZone.run(() => /* set ui properties */)` This question is a faq.

Comment: @Dominik do you mind walking me through a little? I'm a beginner in frontend development.

Comment: Import `NgZone` from Angular and inject it in constructor as a service `constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}` and use e.g. `this.ngZone.run(() => this.lead_list = data;)` This may update your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) to update your UI with data from services. Like:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: `<pre>{{ myList | json }}</pre>`,
})
export class YourComponent {
  myList: unknown;
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private someService: SomeService) {}

  public loadList() {
    this.someService.getList().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        /* add this: */
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.myList = data;
        });
        console.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Hints to your code:

- Don't use arrow-functions as class method. `getLeads = () => {}` > `getLeads() {}`
- Prefer to use camelCase variables. `lead_list` > `leadList`.
- Methods should use camelCase. `ToggleValue()` > `toggleValue()`.
- Use code formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NgZone or ChangeDetectorRef,
Move api calls to ngOnInit()

```js
  constructor(
    private readonly DetailApi: DetailserviceService, 
    private readonly http: HttpClient, 
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { 
    this.status_type = "published";
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getLeads();
  }

  getLeads() {
    this.detailApi.getAllDetails(this.status_type)
     .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.lead_list = data;
          this.cd.detectChanges();
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  togglePublishValue(id) {
    this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/toggle/" + id + "/",{
      headers: this.httpHeaders
    }).subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
    )
    this.getLeads();
  }
```